# Change text-color of validation messages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, colors, textformfield

I want to change the color of the text which is returned when validating a TextFormField. In the following example both the error text and the border of the FormField are red.

[image: Example: Validating a TextFormField]

I want blue for both of them. I tried to override this in **ThemeData** with something like

```
class MyThemes {
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(    
    errorColor: Color(0xFFFE7C7C),
```

With this the color of the border of the TextFormField changes, but not the color of the validation text ("Please enter name of book") still is the default red:

[image: Example: Color of non-validating FormField changes, but not text]

So the [errorColor property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/errorColor.html) does not do what I want.
Unfortunately I cannot access e.g. the [errorStyle property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/errorStyle.html) from ThemeData.

Perhaps the most easy thing would be to change the default color of the error messages. But I don't know where this is defined.
Also any other approach is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to theme `formfield` do it this way

```
ThemeData(     
 inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: nice work dude!